# How to remove forbidden_error?

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I downloaded a jupyter-notebook file. I am trying to open it in jupyter-notebook. I got following error. How can I remove this error

403 : Forbidden
The error was:

Blocking request from unknown origin

Comment: There can be any error but can you try this `c.NotebookApp.allow_origin=''` and `c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
` in the Jupyter settings.